# Plot numbers from different years which are different columns python

Tags: python

I have the following df:

```
   Country   2013   2014   2015    2016   2017
0   USA       40     30     20       30    30
1  Chile      1      2     4        6     1
```

So i need to plot the total Infected (which are the numbers in each year) throughout time per year.

So I did:

`grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="Country", col_wrap=5, hue="Country")`

`grid.map(plt.plot,)`

But this is not going to work because each year is a column and I cannot pass that to the grid.map

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly kind of plot you wanted, but this is one way I got around your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA', 'Chile'],
                   '2013':[40,1],
                  '2014':[30,2],
                  '2015':[20,4],
                  '2016':[30,6],
                  '2017':[30,1]})


df = df.T # This will transpose our df: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html
df.columns = df.iloc[0] #Set the row [0] as our header
df.drop(['Country'], inplace=True, axis=0) # Drop row [0] since we don't want it.
```

[Right now, this is what our df looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRP7h.png)

From our df we can call:

```
df.plot.bar()
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

And we get the desired plot:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szXmN.png)

> Ps. I can't post pictures so far, but please take a look o the links StackOverflow provides for them.

> This code is one way of solving it, but definitely you can approach this by different method. Remember the plot is based on `matplotlib`, so you can customize as such.

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error: ``` "['Country'] not found in axis"```

Comment: Are you calling the plot out of your df? If so, how are you calling the `df.T` method?

Comment: The way I see from your question is that 'Country' is a column in your df

Comment: Yeah it worked, I didn't store the new .T value. One question, do you know how you will plot this with seaborn?

Comment: Are you looking for Seaborn plot's appearance in general or you need a seaborn plot?

Comment: the thing is I was able to do it your way because I added ```subplot = True``` and added two columns so i looks like using FacetGrid seaborn. I can't use seaborn directly because seaborn asks for X and Y when you do grid.map and in this case the DF has 5 columsn (one per year)